# How do I select an option inside an <li> tag using Selenium Webdriver in java?

Tags: java, selenium

I tried using cssSelector and using xpath but could not find how to select one value from the list.

```
r.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'DOLO -650')]"));
r.driver.findElement(By.className("ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content")).click(); 
List<WebElement> opt = r.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content']/li")); 

for (WebElement options:opt) {
    if(options.getText().equals(opt)) {
        options.click(); return;
    } 
} 

WebElement dd = r.driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-1")); dd.click(); 
dd.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[value="+ Product+"]")).click();
r.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li:nth-child(1).NoBulle‌​t.jms-bullet>")).cli‌​ck();
WebElement element = r.driver.findElement(By.name("DOLO -650")); 
element.sendKeys("DOLO -650"); 
element.submit(); 

<ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content"> 
    <li id="ui-id-6" class="ui-menu-item">DOLO -120 60ML</li> 
    <li id="ui-id-7" class="ui-menu-item ui-state-focus">DOLO -650</li>
    <li id="ui-id-8" class="ui-menu-item">DOLO 100ML</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be great if you could share code examples as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: //1 r.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'DOLO -650')]"));

Comment: //2  r.driver.findElement(By.className("ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content")).click();
       List<WebElement> opt = r.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content']/li"));
       for (WebElement options:opt) {
        if(options.getText().equals(opt)) {
         options.click();
         return;
        }
       }

Comment: //3 WebElement dd = r.driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-1"));
       dd.click();
       dd.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[value="+ Product+"]")).click();

Comment: //4 r.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li:nth-child(1).NoBullet.jms-bullet>")).click();

Comment: //5   WebElement element = r.driver.findElement(By.name("DOLO -650"));
                    element.sendKeys("DOLO -650");
                    element.submit();

Comment: on typing Dolo I want to select the tablet name that is in the hidden list of<li> tag

Comment: Could you add that to your answer to make it readable?

Comment: <ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 418px; top: 319.833px; left: 93.2px;">
<li id="ui-id-6" class="ui-menu-item" tabindex="-1">DOLO -120 60ML</li>
<li id="ui-id-7" class="ui-menu-item ui-state-focus" tabindex="-1">DOLO -650</li>
<li id="ui-id-8" class="ui-menu-item" tabindex="-1">DOLO 100ML</li>

Comment: So the above mentioned is the code. Now when I give dolo in text box it list all the tablet name starting with dolo.So I have to select particular tablet name from that list. like DOLO -120 60ML

Comment: So.. I've submitted an edit to include your code. If you have any information regarding the question it's best to edit your question. Doing this helps user in providing you a correct solution. :-)

Comment: would you update the question with the code you have put in your comments.

Comment: My question is, Dolo is the general name. on giving this as input and clicking this in text box the list should be able to select a value from that list. that list is variable list for example if we type cal then it lists tablets starting with cal.

Comment: Now using java in selenium I want to retrieve the value from that list. it is enclosed in <li> tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to try below code to get all li element and select which matches with your expectation

```
List<WebElement> opt = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li")); 

for(WebElement options:opt)
{
    if(option.getText().equals("DOLO -650")) 
    {
        options.click(); 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows this error,org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"DOLO -650"}
Command duration or timeout: 1.02 seconds

Comment: the values dolo or the exact tablet name is excel driven.. I just have to pass dolo and select the value dolo-650 from the list that shows using seelnium.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement autoOptions= driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-1"));
autoOptions.sendKeys("DOLO");
List<WebElement> opt = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content']/li")); 

for(WebElement option:opt)
{
    if(option.getText().equals("DOLO -650")) 
    {
        System.out.println(option);
        option.click(); 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: the values dolo or the exact tablet name is excel driven.. I just have to pass the value and select the value.

Comment: Then instead of "DOLO" in sendKeys(), enter the value you read from the excel. If you read excel details and loaded to a variable (String), mention the string variable in sendKeys()

Comment: @sharmee first check whether the above code is running or not, then you can modify the code to be able to incorporate your excel read values. etc

Comment: its not running